# How to Display Unpark Parked Conversations in Twilio Flex UI?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

I'm using Twilio's Park Conversation feature to keep track of chat history with users. The [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/conversations/park-an-interaction) shows how to park a conversation and view its history when the user messages back. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to display the parked conversation on the Flex UI and allow agents to resume or unpark it from their side. The documentation mentions the [flow of unparking](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/conversations/park-an-interaction#agent-picks-up-a-parked-interaction-channel) from the agent side, but it doesn't provide details on how to implement this in the Flex UI. Can you help with that?